# Exibir navbar apenas quando o usuário rolar para cima no iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, touch, mobile-safari

Estou usando a [técnica de Marius Craciunoiu](https://medium.com/p/67bbaae9a78c) para exibir toda a minha navbar quando o usuário rolar a tela para cima.

Então, aqui está meu código **JavaScript** (usando jQuery):

```js
var delta, didScroll, lastScrollTop, navbarHeight;

delta = 5;
lastScrollTop = 0;
navbarHeight = $('.navbar').outerHeight();

$(window).on('scroll touchmove', function() {
  didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
  if (didScroll) {
    hasScrolled();
    didScroll = false;
  }
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
  var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

  if (Math.abs(lastScrollTop - scrollTop) <= delta) { return; }

  if (scrollTop > lastScrollTop && scrollTop > navbarHeight) {
    $('.navbar').addClass('scrolling');
  } else {
    if (scrollTop + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
      $('.navbar').removeClass('scrolling');
    }
  }

  lastScrollTop = scrollTop;
}
```

Para facilitar, eu coloquei o meu código no http://jsfiddle.net/caio/7HrK7/. Se você quiser testar no iOS, será necessário entrar por outro endereço http://fiddle.jshell.net/caio/7HrK7/show/light/.

**VIDEO:** http://hiperload.com/s/ua5k53n0x/d.mp4?inline

Como vocês podem ver, meu código funciona no desktop e em telefones Android, mas no iOS, é necessário inserir um evento touch para responder enquanto o evento de rolar acontece, ou então a ação só será disparada no final do movimento. Eu tentei adicionar o evento `touchmove`, mas sem sucesso. Vocês podem me ajudar?

Answer (score 2):

Não é possível fazer isso no iOS. Há uma explicação aqui:

http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html

> Basicamente, o vento só funciona quando inicia o toque na tela e quando para de tocar, quando você move não é realizado nenhum evento.

Para comprovar, fiz esse código abaixo em `JavaScript` para mostrar os segundos enquanto toca na tela, e só funciona quando inicia o toque e quando solta, se ficar segurando a tela e movendo não funciona:

```
var iOS = ( navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/g) ? true : false )
    if (iOS){
    document.addEventListener('touchmove', function() {
        $('#emtemporeal').html((new Date()).getSeconds());
    }, false);
}
```

Eu já havia passado por isso uma vez ao customizar um navbar e acabei desabilitando isso ao acessar pelo iPad, mas o motivo principal nem foi por causa desse detalhe, foi mais porque o navbar fixo ocupa no iPad um espaço considerável, visto que a tela é pequena comparada a um desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Meu palpite é que você não deve usar o evento `touchmove`, já que o Safari só vai executar o código "depois" do ultimo step do scroll da viewport.

No video, fica bem evidente isso, então você pode tentar usar o evento `touchend` e `touchcancel`, pois eles serão executados logo após o gesto touch.